# save and load value from registry in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, registry

I have an application where the user select configuration, I need to write to function one to save the configuration when the application is closed and other load the configuration when the application is loaded, i need to use registry would you able to help me by giving me 2 small example how to save and to load from the registry. 
thank you 
Jp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "My" Class in VB contains almost everything you need.
To read data:

```
My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.GetValue("mykey")
```

To write data:

```
My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.SetValue("mykey", "myvalue")
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [Registry Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5f1xf5kf.aspx). The KEYS exposed by this class are

- CurrentUser - Stores information about user preferences.
- LocalMachine - Stores configuration information for the local machine.
- ClassesRoot - Stores information about types (and classes) and their properties.
- Users - Stores information about the default user configuration.
- PerformanceData - Stores performance information for software components.
- CurrentConfig - Stores non-user-specific hardware information.

It's important to understand the the use of these keys so information can be saved for user specific instances or machine.

I wasn't sure what version of .NET Framework you are using.

Sample data from MS

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System
Imports System.Security.Permissions
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Public Class RegKey
    Shared Sub Main()

        ' Create a subkey named Test9999 under HKEY_CURRENT_USER.
        Dim test9999 As RegistryKey = _
            Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Test9999")

        ' Create two subkeys under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Test9999.
        test9999.CreateSubKey("TestName").Close()
        Dim testSettings As RegistryKey = _
            test9999.CreateSubKey("TestSettings")

        ' Create data for the TestSettings subkey.
        testSettings.SetValue("Language", "French")
        testSettings.SetValue("Level", "Intermediate")
        testSettings.SetValue("ID", 123)
        testSettings.Close()

        ' Print the information from the Test9999 subkey.
        Console.WriteLine("There are {0} subkeys under Test9999.", _
            test9999.SubKeyCount.ToString())
        For Each subKeyName As String In test9999.GetSubKeyNames()
            Dim tempKey As RegistryKey = _
                test9999.OpenSubKey(subKeyName)
            Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf & "There are {0} values for " & _
                "{1}.", tempKey.ValueCount.ToString(), tempKey.Name)
            For Each valueName As String In tempKey.GetValueNames()
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-8}: {1}", valueName, _
                    tempKey.GetValue(valueName).ToString())
            Next
        Next

        ' Delete the ID value.
        testSettings = test9999.OpenSubKey("TestSettings", True)
        testSettings.DeleteValue("id")

        ' Verify the deletion.
        Console.WriteLine(CType(testSettings.GetValue( _
            "id", "ID not found."), String))
        testSettings.Close()

        ' Delete or close the new subkey.
        Console.Write(vbCrLf & "Delete newly created " & _
            "registry key? (Y/N) ")
        If Char.ToUpper(Convert.ToChar(Console.Read())) = "Y"C Then
            Registry.CurrentUser.DeleteSubKeyTree("Test9999")
            Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf & "Registry key {0} deleted.", _
                test9999.Name)
        Else
            Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf & "Registry key {0} closed.", _
                test9999.ToString())
            test9999.Close()
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```